# How to send string array data with okhttp MultipartBuilder data

Tags: android, okhttp

I am an android developer. I develop an application. I have a problem. I want to send string array data with okhttp multipart data. But I can not do it. Because "addFormDataPart" method is required string variable. I can not use that method(addFormDataPart). I want to send string array data. What can I do?

Please help me.

My source code:

```
private void String sendData(String serverURL, String[] arrayData){
RequestBody requestBody;
requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("arraydata", arrayData)
                        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    void String sendData(String serverURL, String[] arrayData){
        String commaSeparatedValues = TextUtils.join(",", arrayData);
        multiPartBuilder.addFormDataPart("key[]", commaSeparatedValues);
    }
```

Note: the key here is important it should have "[]"

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
private void String sendData(String serverURL, String[] arrayData){
  RequestBody requestBody;
  requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                    .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("arraydata", getToString(arrayData))
                    .build();
}

public String getToString(String[] arrayData) {
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(arrayData[i]);
    if (i < arrayData.length - 1) {
        stringBuilder.append(",");
    }
  }
  return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

Map<String, Long> params = new HashMap<String, Long>();
params.put("msisdn", 8801701340061l);

JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject(params);


RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parameter.toString());

RequestBody requestBodyy = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addPart(
                Headers.of("content-type", "form-data; name=\"image\""),
                RequestBody.create(null, "Square Logo"))
        .addPart(
                Headers.of("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"),
                body)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

把`String[] arrayData`拼接成 `"one,two,three"` 这种形式：

```
 public String getToString(String[] arrayData) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(arrayData[i]);
        if (i < arrayData.length - 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(",");
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

再传值：

```
.addFormDataPart("arraydata", getToString(arrayData))
```

Comment: write your answer in English please