# Passing arrays in multipart POST using Okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm building an app that requires an API call that has array in its POST body request. I'm using OkHttp 2.6 to request for API.

The request in Postman looks like this:

[image: postman-ss]

I have tried several ways of writing `RequestBody` in order to achieve this,

1. First method

   ```
   RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
           .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
           .addFormDataPart("app_token", MY_TOKEN)
           .addFormDataPart("user_id", 377)
           .addFormDataPart("group_id", String.valueOf(groupId))
           .addFormDataPart("key_id", deals.toString())
           .addFormDataPart("img", filename + ".jpg", fileBody)
           .build();
   ```
2. Second method

   ```
   RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
           .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
           .addFormDataPart("app_token", MY_TOKEN)
           .addFormDataPart("user_id", 377)
           .addFormDataPart("group_id", String.valueOf(groupId))
           .addFormDataPart("key_id[0]", "33")
           .addFormDataPart("key_id[1]", "34")
           .addFormDataPart("img[0]", filename + ".jpg", fileBody)
           .build();
   ```
3. Third method, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049054/how-to-send-string-array-data-with-okhttp-multipartbuilder-data).

   ```
   MediaType json = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
   Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < deals.size(); i++) {
       params.put("key_id["+i+"]", Integer.valueOf(deals.get(i).getUid()));
   }
   JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject(params);
   RequestBody theBody = RequestBody.create(json, parameter.toString());


   RequestBody requestBodyyy = new MultipartBuilder()
           .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
           .addFormDataPart("app_token", MY_TOKEN)
           .addFormDataPart("user_id", 377)
           .addFormDataPart("group_id", String.valueOf(groupId))
           .addPart(theBody)
           .addFormDataPart("img[0]", filename + ".jpg", fileBody)
           .build();
   ```

But, none of them are working.

What is the correct way of doing this? I also need the array size to be dynamic as I'm not passing a static one.

Comment: I think your first approach should work, but you didn't use the right key for ```group_id``` it should be ```group_id[0]``` or more generic ```group_id[i]```. And the same should be for the ```img``` key.

Comment: That is like equivalent to approach #2, which is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Retrofit and Gson

```
private class AddImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Imageuploadpojo, Imageuploadpojo> {


        ApiCall a;
        String path1,path2;

        private AddImageAsyncTask(View vs, String path1,String path2) {
            this.vs = vs;
            this.path1 = path1;
             this.path2 = path2;         
            a = retrofit2.create(ApiCall.class);
        }



        @Override
        protected Imageuploadpojo doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Map<String, RequestBody> typedfile = new HashMap<String, RequestBody>();
            File f = new File(path1);
             File f2 = new File(path2);
            if (f.exists()) {
                RequestBody requestFile =
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f);
                String filename = f.getName();
                typedfile.put("fileToUpload" + "\"; filename=\"" + filename, requestFile);
                //   typedfile.put("img[0]" + count, requestFile);
            }
              if (f2.exists()) {
                RequestBody requestFile =
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f2);
                String filename = f.getName();
                typedfile.put("fileToUpload" + "\"; filename=\"" + filename, requestFile);
                //   typedfile.put("img[1]" + count, requestFile);
            }

            // asynchronous
            // Create a call instance for looking up Retrofit contributors.
            Call<Imageuploadpojo> call = a.ImageCall(typedfile);
            // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to the library.
            Imageuploadpojo c = null;
            try {
                c = call.execute().body();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Imageuploadpojo c) {
            super.onPostExecute(c);

        }
    }
```

See this you can get idea. Or try it in retrofit

**Code updated:**

```
    //Create Hashmap:

         Map<String, RequestBody> typedfile = new HashMap<String, RequestBody>();

    //Add your file path

     File f2 = new File(path2);

    //Check the file is exist or not
     if (f2.exists()) {
    //Then Create RequestBody add file in second perameter
    RequestBody requestFile =
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f2);

      typedfile.put("img[1]" + "\"; filename=\"" + filename, requestFile);
//"img[1]" is parameter
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. May I see the `ImageCall` method; how did you pass HashMap into form data?

Comment: My issue with this approach is the `typedFile` is empty. How did you do it on your side?

Comment: Can you check now. typedFile is a HashMap so it won't be empty. Can you look on the answer again? I have updated the code. It may help you I think so. If you get any doubt ask me. @AimanB

Comment: Ah, now it's working. I've modified your code a bit to put into loops. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Heh, the solution seems easy. I've managed to solve this issue, so I'm gonna write here anyway for anyone seeking the same solution.

```
MultipartBuilder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBuilder()
        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("token", MY_TOKEN)
        .addFormDataPart("user_id", user_id)
        .addFormDataPart("group_id", group_id)
        // .addFormDataPart("img[0]", filename + ".jpg", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file));

for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("key_id[" + i + "]", keys.get(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    filename = Utils.getSimpleTimestamp();
    multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("img[" + i + "]", filename + ".jpg", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), files.get(i)));
}

RequestBody requestBody = multipartBuilder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(API_URL)
        .post(requestBody)
        .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data;")
        .build();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
```